# R ggplot2: place value of column on top of stacked bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, stacked-chart

There might be a duplicate, but I do not find an answer that applies to my particular case...

I just have a very simple data frame like the one below, with counts in two columns (`Number_NonHit_Cells`, `Number_Hit_Cells`) that I want to show in stacked bars, having the value of another column (`Freq`) placed on top of the stacked bars.

The MWE below is the best I have been able to get so far, but I only need the value of `Freq` once, and at the very top of the bars combined...

It would even be better if `Freq` could be calculated inside the `ggplot2` call.

This is my MWE:

```
  clono_df_long <- data.frame(Clonotype=LETTERS[1:5], Number_Hit_Cells=c(234,56,568,34,46),
                              Number_NonHit_Cells=c(c(52,12,234,21,31)))
  clono_df_long$Clonotype_Size <- clono_df_long$Number_Hit_Cells+clono_df_long$Number_NonHit_Cells
  clono_df_long$Freq <- round(clono_df_long$Number_Hit_Cells/clono_df_long$Clonotype_Size,4)*100
  clono_df_long <- as.data.frame(tidyr::pivot_longer(clono_df_long,
                                                     -c(Clonotype,Clonotype_Size,Freq),
                                                     names_to = "Cells", values_to = "Value"))
  clono_df_long$Clonotype <- factor(clono_df_long$Clonotype, levels=unique(clono_df_long$Clonotype))
  clono_df_long$Cells <- factor(clono_df_long$Cells, levels=c('Number_NonHit_Cells','Number_Hit_Cells'))
  P <- ggplot2::ggplot(clono_df_long, ggplot2::aes(x=Clonotype, y=Value, fill=Cells)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray70', 'gray40')) +
    ggplot2::geom_text(ggplot2::aes(label=paste0(Freq,'%')), vjust=-1) +
    ggplot2::theme_light()
  grDevices::pdf(file='test.pdf', height=6, width=6)
  print(P)
  grDevices::dev.off()
```

Which produces this:

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
clono_df_long$Freq <- ifelse(clono_df_long$Cells == "Number_NonHit_Cells", clono_df_long$Freq, NA)

ggplot2::ggplot(clono_df_long, ggplot2::aes(x=Clonotype, y=Value, fill=Cells)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray70', 'gray40')) +
  #ggplot2::geom_text(ggplot2::aes(label=paste0(Freq,'%')), vjust=-1) +
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Freq/100) ),position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, but I still get the warnings saying it removed the NAs... is there a cleaner way to do it? Otherwise I will stick to this

Comment: @DaniCee NA's it remove are I replace it by purpose. That warning does not make any problems.